# How do I list multisite users for the current site only

Tags: multisite, multisite-user-management

I'm looking for a way of selecting the users for one site within a multisite set up.  Can anyone tell me how to do this please?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
$user_search = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, display_name, user_email FROM ".$wpdb->base_prefix."users");
```

but this selects all users across the multisite.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[get_users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function is the method you should use to query users, and by default it retrieves only users of the current blog in a multisite setup.